# Powershell Tcp-IP, how to, Connect / SendData / ReadResult / Disconnect

Tags: powershell, tcp, powershell-remoting, network-printers

I need to query printer over JetDirect protocol (Tcp-IP Port 9100)

I already write the code to connect and disconnect, but for put and read data i have some problem :(

```
'printer.local:9100' | Connect-TcpHost | Disconnect-TcpHost
```

result

```
TcpDestNodes     IsOpen Latency Query
------------     ------ ------- -----
printer.local:9100   True  0,7065 {}
```

My code

```
function Connect-TcpHost (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]$Dest,
    $TCPtimeout=250
    ) {
    Begin {

    } Process {
        ($HostName, $port) = $Dest.split(':')
        Write-Verbose "$HostName : $port"
        $tcpClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient
        $connect = $tcpClient.BeginConnect($HostName,$port,$null,$null)

        Write-Verbose "Connecting..."
        $timeMs = (Measure-Command {
            $wait = $connect.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne($TCPtimeout,$false)
            Write-Verbose "Connecting 2..."
        }).TotalMilliseconds
        If (!$wait) {
            Write-error "$HostName : $Port"
            Write-Verbose "Close connections..."
            $tcpClient.Close()
            $tcpClient.Dispose()
            return;
        }
        [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            TcpDestNodes = $dest
            tcpClient = $tcpClient
            connect = $connect
            IsOpen = $true
            Latency = $timeMs
            Query = @()
        }
    } End {

    }
}
function Disconnect-TcpHost (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]$ObjTcp
    ) {
    Begin {
    } Process {
        Write-Verbose "Disconnecting..."
        $ObjTcp.tcpClient.Close()
        $ObjTcp.tcpClient.Dispose()
        [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            TcpDestNodes = $ObjTcp.TcpDestNodes
            IsOpen = $ObjTcp.IsOpen
            Latency = $ObjTcp.Latency
            Query = $ObjTcp.Query
        }
    } End {

    }
}
```

Comment: You're using telnet to connect to the printer so that is already plenty of blogs on this subject available. [This one](https://thesurlyadmin.com/2013/04/04/using-powershell-as-a-telnet-client/) that covers the process

Answer (score 1):

I Write 2 new function Put-TcpHost() and Read-TcpHost()

```
'printer.local:9100' | Connect-TcpHost -verbose | Put-TcpHost -query '@PJL INFO ID' -verbose | Read-TcpHost -verbose | Disconnect-TcpHost -verbose
```

return

```
TcpDestNodes : 10.48.5.102:9100
IsOpen       : True
Latency      : 0,8351
Query        : {@{Type=Query; Data=System.Object[]}, @{Type=Answer; Data=System.Object[]}}
```

[image]

my full Tcp-Tools.ps1

```
function Connect-TcpHost (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]$Dest,
    $TCPtimeout=250
    ) {
    Begin {

    } Process {
        ($HostName, $port) = $Dest.split(':')
        Write-Verbose "$HostName : $port"
        $tcpClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient
        $connect = $tcpClient.BeginConnect($HostName,$port,$null,$null)

        Write-Verbose "Connecting..."
        $timeMs = (Measure-Command {
            $wait = $connect.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne($TCPtimeout,$false)
        }).TotalMilliseconds
        If (!$wait) {
            Write-error "$HostName : $Port"
            Write-Verbose "Echec, Close socket..."
            $tcpClient.Close()
            $tcpClient.Dispose()
            return;
        }
        Write-Verbose "Connection Available"
        [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            TcpDestNodes = $dest
            tcpClient = $tcpClient
            connect = $connect
            IsOpen = $true
            Latency = $timeMs
            Query = @()
        }
    } End {

    }
}
function Put-TcpHost (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]$ObjTcp,[string]$query
    ) {
    Begin {

    } Process {
        if ($ObjTcp.tcpClient.Connected) {
            Write-Verbose "Send > $query"
            $ObjTcp.query += [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                    Type = 'Query'
                    Data = @($query)
            }
            $data = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$query`n")
            $stream = $ObjTcp.TcpClient.GetStream()
            $stream.Write($data, 0, $data.Length)
        } else {
            Write-error "N'est plus connecte !"
            $ObjTcp.tcpClient.Close()
            $ObjTcp.tcpClient.Dispose()
            return;
        }
        $ObjTcp
    } End {

    }
}
function Read-TcpHost (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]$ObjTcp,
    $timeout=2500
    ) {
    Begin {
        $step = 25
    } Process {
        $i=$timeout/$step
        Write-Verbose ">  Waiting Answer"
        While ([int64]$ObjTcp.tcpClient.Available -le 0 -and $i--) {
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $step
        }
        Write-Verbose "Reply $($timeout-$i*$step)ms > Bytes available: $($ObjTcp.tcpClient.Available)"
        If ([int64]$ObjTcp.tcpClient.Available -gt 0) {
            $stringBuilder = New-Object Text.StringBuilder
            try {
                $stream = $ObjTcp.TcpClient.GetStream()
                $bindResponseBuffer = New-Object Byte[] -ArgumentList $ObjTcp.tcpClient.Available
                [Int]$response = $stream.Read($bindResponseBuffer, 0, $bindResponseBuffer.count)  
                $Null = $stringBuilder.Append(($bindResponseBuffer | ForEach {[char][int]$_}) -join '')

                Write-Verbose "Read > $(@($stringBuilder.Tostring() -split("`n"))[1])"
                $ObjTcp.query += [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                    Type = 'Answer'
                    Data = @($stringBuilder.Tostring() -split("`n"))
                 }
            } catch {
                Write-error "Probleme !"
                $ObjTcp.tcpClient.Close()
                $ObjTcp.tcpClient.Dispose()
                return;
            }
        }
        $ObjTcp
    } End {

    }
}
function Disconnect-TcpHost (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]$ObjTcp
    ) {
    Begin {
    } Process {
        Write-Verbose "Disconnecting..."
        $ObjTcp.tcpClient.Close()
        $ObjTcp.tcpClient.Dispose()
        [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            TcpDestNodes = $ObjTcp.TcpDestNodes
            IsOpen = $ObjTcp.IsOpen
            Latency = $ObjTcp.Latency
            Query = $ObjTcp.Query
        }
    } End {

    }
}
```

Comment: @JamesC. Self answers are allowed and even encouraged, please see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: my code Put / Read, not works at my first post and now is not perfect, i need your answers or your improve ideas